# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id при запуске фрагмента

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragment

Всем привет. Я тут решил начать осваивать такой элемент UI как Fragment, но у меня кое-что пошло не так. Дело в том, что я сделал приложение которое при старте открывает пустой Fragment, но приложение сразу "вылетает" со следующей ошибкой:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f080155 com.masterok.testapp:id/placeHolder) for fragment MainFragment{f9b5608} (4b1096cb-a0bc-4cc0-a9ff-2975f29359ce id=0x7f080155)(com.masterok.testapp:id/placeHolder) for fragment MainFragment{f9b5608} (4b1096cb-a0bc-4cc0-a9ff-2975f29359ce id=0x7f080155)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:513)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:282)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2189)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2100)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2002)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3138)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:3072)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:251)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:502)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:246)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1473)
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:8082)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStartActivity(ActivityThread.java:3732)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence(TransactionExecutor.java:221)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath(TransactionExecutor.java:201)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:173)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2253)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7870)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:550)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
```

Как решить эту проблему? Код MainActivity и MainFragment ниже:

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

MainActivity.kt:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        supportFragmentManager
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.placeHolder, MainFragment.newInstance())
            .commit()
    }
}
```

fragmen_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/placeHolder"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".fragments.MainFragment">
    
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Fragment1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

MainFragment.kt:

```
class MainFragment : Fragment() {
    private lateinit var binding: FragmentMainBinding

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        binding = FragmentMainBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        return binding.root
    }

    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        fun newInstance() = MainFragment()
    }
}
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галку слева от него

Answer (score 0, accepted):

После того, как я внимательно изучил эти две разметки, я понял почему появилась ошибка. Проблема не была связана с несоответствии требованиям binding. А в том, что id "placeHolder" нужно было присваивать не контейнеру фрагмента, а контейнеру активити. Когда я решил эту проблему, ошибка исчезла. Надеюсь, этот ответ вам поможет.

Answer (score 1):

Допускаю что у вас в проекте нет сгенерированного Binding файла для фрагмента. То есть вы создали разметку, но она не соответствует требованиям binding:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>
    </data>

    // layout content
</layout>
```

поэтому у вас биндинг фрагмента как бы "не знает" про вашу разметку ничего. Чтобы сгенерировать макет вызовите быстрые действия на корневом контейнере разметки для фрагмента и выберите пункт Convert to databinding layout, по итогу у вас будет что-то типа такого:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>
    </data>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    android:id="@+id/placeHolder"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".fragments.MainFragment">
    
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Fragment1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

      </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

и дальше у вас класс фрагмента найдет все зависимости для работы с макетом. Вот есть хороший [туториал](https://blog.logrocket.com/data-binding-android-tutorial-with-examples/) и [доки](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding)

Comment: Я это сделал, но у меня опять появляется та же ошибка. Вот даже папка проекта: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1taJTexu853csuFmY3rub4oyu8YGML4vW?usp=sharing

Comment: попробуйте Invalidate cashes and restart. Пересоберите проект, почистите его, и подключали ли вы в градл файле датабиндинг?